# Why does the grid look different?

Tags: no-computers

Relatively easy puzzle:

[image: grid]

Why does the grid look different?

Comment: Why so many downvotes :(

Comment: The downvotes are probably a combination of fatigue and a feeling that this puzzle is trivially easy...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message goes

> **GRID LOOK DIFFERENT BECAUSE MY EXCALIDRAW FILE GOT CORRUPTED AND RESETS WHENEVER I REFRESH THE PAGE.**

> Read what is highlighted yellow left to right from top down first and then red.
>  [image]